# Infinite cartesian product from Herbert Enderton's Elements of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

I am reading Enderton's book [*Elements of set theory*](https://books.google.it/books?id=DOnkAH-I02sC&pg=PA54) and I am having hard time understanding Infinite cartesian product section in which he define's product of $H(i)$'s.

Could you please explain in other simple words or by giving an example.

PS : I am a self learner

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Probably a bunch more have explanations. Search the site.

Comment: Start from the *cartesian product*.  What is $A \times B$ ? The set of pairs where the first "coordinate" belongs to $A$ and the second one belongs to $B$ : $A \times B = \{ (a,b) \mid a \in A \text { and } b \in B \}$. We can iterate it for $n$ finite whatever : every element of $A_1 \times \ldots \times A_n$ will be an $n$-uple for which the "$i$-th coordinate" belongs to $A_i$.

Comment: Now, instead of the $A_i$'s, consider a set $I$ whatever and a "family" of sets $\{ H(i) \}$ : we say that the family is "indexed by $I$". 
We generalize the above construction in this way : the members of $\Pi_{i \in I} H(i)$ are "$I$-tuples" for which the "$i$-th coordinate" (i.e., the value at $i$) is an element of $H(i)$.

Comment: thanks @MauroALLEGRANZA  but what about the part where he says {f | f is a function with domain I and for every i in I f(i) belongs to H(i)}

Comment: In set theory an $n$-uple $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ of elements of $A$ is a function $f : \{ 1,2,\ldots, n \} \to A$. Thus the $I$-uple is a function $f$ with domain $I$ sich that every "value" $f(i)$ belongs to $H(i)$.

Comment: "infinite elements" ???? The trick of the construction is exactly to avoid "listing" the elements of $I$ (compare with the *finite* case : $\{ 1,2,\ldots, n \}$). Thus, it works also for $I$ **infinite**.

Comment: I get it now. Once we index H with I than there should not be any problem even if I is infinite. Thanks for the help. really appreciate it @MauroALLEGRANZA